# Load new content in box when clicked on

Tags: jquery, html

I am trying to create this box, and when you click on it, new text is loaded. 
The html code is as following:

```
<div class="hPage"><a name="Project">PROJECT</a>
    <div class="boxP" style="width:960px;height:840px;border:1px solid black;">
        <div class="gallery"> 
            <div id="div1">
                First story to be read              
            </div>
            <div id="div2">
                Second story to be read
            </div>
            <div id="div3">
                Third story to be read
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I have tried to work with click function of jQuery, but I constantly fail to get it work properly. Does anyone know how to accomplish it?

Comment: new text is loaded??

Comment: click function you tried?

Answer (score 0):

Where's your click function? Anyway, the function should look like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $(".boxP").click(function () {
    $(this).html("Loading new content...").load("URL");
  });
});
```

This fires an AJAX call every time you click on the `<div>`. Immediatel upon clicking, it displays a message `"Loading new content..."`. Once the content is fetched from the URL, it loads into the `<div>`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
(function()
{   
    var divName, divNumber;
    $('.hPage > .boxP > .gallery > div').hide();
    $('.hPage > .boxP > .gallery > div#div1').show()
    $('.hPage > .boxP > .gallery > div').on('click', function()
    {
        divName = $(this).attr('id');
        divNumber = parseInt(divName.substring(3, 4));
        divNumber++;
        $(this).hide();
        $('.hPage > .boxP > .gallery > div#div'+divNumber).show();
    });     
})();
```